# C - Segfault on a loop over char *

Tags: c, pointers

I write a C programm to display a words on a led message board.

I loop over a char* containing my message and after a few processing, i give a segfault.

I have isolated my problem in this code (the segfault appear on the scrollMsg() function) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024

void setMsg()
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    char *data;

    key = ftok("my_test_key", 'R');
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    strncpy(data, "TEST", SHM_SIZE);
}

char * getMsg()
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    char *msg;

    key   = ftok("my_test_key", 'R');
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    msg   = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    return msg;
}

void scrollMsg(char *buf)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    for (p=buf; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        printf("%p\n", p);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *msg = NULL;

    setMsg();

    do {
        msg = getMsg();

        printf("%s\n", msg);

        scrollMsg(msg);
    } while(1);
}
```

Someone can explain me why this append ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this `printf("%p\n", p);` intended? Also, check that your pointers are not `NULL` before dereferencing.

Comment: please do error handling for return from `shmat` function. Verify if your string have a null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have run out of your process address space. You are constantly attaching shared memory, making OS chose another spot for another attachment, but you never detach a shared region.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, your are right.

Here is a working code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024

void setMsg()
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    char *data;

    key = ftok("test_key", 'R');
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    strncpy(data, "TEST", SHM_SIZE);
}

char * getMsg()
{
    key_t key = 0;
    int shmid = 0;
    char *msg = NULL;

    key   = ftok("test_key", 'R');
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    msg   = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

    return msg;
}

void scrollMsg(char *buf)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    for (p=buf; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        printf("%p\n", p);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *msg = NULL;

    setMsg();

    msg = getMsg();

    do {
        printf("msg:%s\n", msg);

        scrollMsg(msg);
    } while(1);
}
```

Thanks for your help !